# Input Manager in Unity (PS3 controller)

Tags: button, input, printing, unity-game-engine

I dont entirely get why my call to actions scripts aren't working? Im guessing I must be filling in the details incorrectly in my Input Manager in Unity.

Here is a script I found and trying to reuse and added to my FPC:

```js
#pragma strict

var comboCount: int = 0;
 
 function Update () 
 {
     if (Input.GetKey("KeyCode.joystick button 2"))
         comboFunction();
 }
 
 function comboFunction ()
 {
     switch (comboCount)
     {
         case 0:
             print ("Idle");
             comboCount += 1;
             break;
         case 1:
             print ("Attack1");
             comboCount += 1;
             break;
         case 2:
             print ("Attack2");
             comboCount += 1;
             break;
         case 3:
             print ("Attack3");
             comboCount = 0;
             break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your configured InputManager axis use [Input.GetAxis()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

I cant see if you attached n image of your [InputManager](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) configuration but you need to pass the same axis name configuired on InputManager as string for Input.GetAxis("axisName")

Comment: I think Input.GetKey will not work for customized InputManager axis and this parameter string is wrong too you can use Input.GetKey(KeyCode.{valid_value}). Where valid_value you can find on KeyCode documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

Comment: I am not doing something right. I have updated my code:

` if (Input.GetAxis("JoystickButton2"))
         comboFunction();`

here is a link to a screenshot of my Input Manager: 
http://workupload.com/file/diAAqQcA

Comment: Try to set your positive button value as "joystick button 0" without the "", dead to 0.001 and Joy Num I think is not important as you are trying to get a button and not axyx but set it to Joystick 1 just in case and test if one of your buttons now fires comboFunction().

Comment: As an contingency in case your joystick driver or configuration is causing any problems you can set "alt positive button" to value "space" without "", it will make space bar acting as second/alternative input for this same command.

Comment: Aah its still not working :( I specifically want a controller to work with my game, so space is not going to work. I just dont get it. It should work.

Comment: the space bar was just to help understand if your joystic input is the problem or if is your configuration, so if you set the spacebar as alternative command it works and joystick doesn't? if so you need to check your joystick connection/configuration and if it works out of unity (in some another game or on controller calibration of your OS)

Comment: I have updated my code to:

if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))

and edited my Input Manager as specified. But theres no action at all.

Comment: use if(Input.GetAxis("JoystickButton2")){comboFunction();} if you want to use what you configured in Input Manager. Set "space" (without the "") in your "Alt Positive Button" field on the axis that you named JoystickButton2. If you already didn't set Dead field to 0.001 do it too. Now pressing space bar once may print in your console something like "Idle" if it doesn't check on runtime if your script is attached to some active gameObject.